# Finding maximum sum possible of two numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

"-1 7 8 -5 4  " This is the array we have to find the maximum alternate sum possible of two integers . For example, for this array the output should be 8+4=12 as the array starts from index 0 and incrementation should be 2

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question does not specify clearly what the requirements are, and does not show any effort to solve the problem yourself. Please see [ask].

Comment: Take two maximum values and sum them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per assuming few conditions like provided array size and array data type to be integer you can use the following program for reference.
This program takes the no. of elements and array as input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(){

    int n;
    int a[100];
    printf("Size of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Enter array element a[%d]:", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int max = INT_MIN;
    int sum = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++){
        sum = a[i] + a[i+2];
        if(max < sum){
            max = sum;
            k = i;
            l = i+2;
        }
    }
    printf("max sum is: %d using index: a[%d] and a[%d]\n", max, k, l);
}
```

*INPUT*

5

-1 7 8 -5 4

*OUTPUT*

max sum is: 12 using index: a[2] and a[4]

Comment: Max sum is 7+8=15. Your code seem to do something completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: The sum should be of alternate indexes (with a difference of two as the question suggests) that's why 7 and 8 cannot be considered. 7 has to be added with -5 as the difference of indexes are 2 but it turns out that 7-5 = 2 is not the maximum sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code is correct -

```
#include
int main(){

    int n;
    int a[100];
    printf("Size of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Enter array element a[%d]:", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int max = INT_MIN;
    int sum = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        sum = a[i] + a[i+1];
        if(max < sum){
            max = sum;
            k = i;
            l = i+1;
        }
    }
    printf("max sum is: %d using index: a[%d] and a[%d]\n", max, k, l);
}
```